# Can I undo composer's dump-autoload?

Tags: composer-php

I incorrectly issued `composer dump-autoload -o` on my PHP project (thinking it did something else!). Is there a way to undo this?

I found an auto-generated file in `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` - will just deleting this file do the trick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, manually removing all files of the autoloader in the  `vendor/composer/` folder should work.

So, all `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` files and the `include_paths.php`.

By using  `dump-autoload -o` Composer creates an optimized `autoload_classmap.php` file.

If in doubt, drop the whole `vendor/composer` folder and do a `composer install` afterwards. Composer will then auto-generate the files again.

Comment: Please do not do a `composer update` afterwards, it will update all dependencies if there are updates. Use `composer install` instead to install all dependencies and regenerate the autoloader