# Exception class not found

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to define a simple exception hierarchy:

> Exception -> ServiceDenied -> IpBlocked

ServiceDenied.php:

```php
<?php
namespace Morpher\Ws3Client;


class ServiceDenied extends \Exception
{
    function __construct(string $message, int $code)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
}
```

IpBlocked.php:

```php
<?php
namespace Morpher\Ws3Client;

use Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied; // this line is greyed out by the IDE

class IpBlocked extends ServiceDenied // this line has the error
{
    function __construct(string $message, int $code)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
}
```

Both files are in the same folder.

Now when I run unit tests, I get the following error:

```
Error : Class 'Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied' not found
 C:\Code\morpher-ws3-php-client\src\exceptions\IpBlocked.php:6
 C:\Code\morpher-ws3-php-client\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:571
 C:\Code\morpher-ws3-php-client\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:428
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Removing the greyed out line does not have any effect. It still says "Class 'Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied' not found".

Sorry if it's something obvious. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Please share more details, like the file structure and the configuration of your autoloader

Comment: Potential reason for the greyed out line is that you are in the same namespace as your ServiceDenied file. You can directly say `use ServiceDenied` instead of `use Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied`.

Comment: `use Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied; // this line is greyed out by the IDE` - that's because your IDE has recognized it as superfluous - you already are in the namespace `Morpher\Ws3Client` there, as per your statement two lines above - so the use of the "naked" class name `ServiceDenied` would already resolve to `Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied` in that context.

Comment: Not related (directly) to your problem, but there's a pattern called [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) which encourages a common class and file name convention. For instance, you'd say that all objects in the namespace `Morpher\Ws3Client` live in the `src` folder, so `Morpher\Ws3Client\ServiceDenied` would be `src/ServiceDenied.php`, and `Morpher\Ws3Client\Thing\Stuff` would be `/src/Thing/Stuff.php`. Following this pattern makes writing autoloaders much easier, which makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 1):

Check how your program is autoloading classes.
You can test if this is the issue if you add `require()` functions in your classes
e.g. `require('ServiceDenied.php');` in `IpBlocked.php` and then in the file where you test things `require('IpBlocked.php');`

or just check the autoloader logic...

Comment: I didn't downvote this, and the person that did it didn't explain (and they usually don't), but my guess is that this feels like more of a comment than an answer. However, I also think you are generally correct (or at least on the same track), and the OP should look at how things are autoloaded. The fact that they said "unit tests" could also potentially mean that a different autoloader is being invoked instead of the main one.

Comment: Thanks, you got me looking in the right direction. I have posted my answer with more details.

Comment: I know it is more of a comment than an answer, but I don't have a reputation for just a comment.  So basically the only way to help in a way was to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Being new to PHP, I just blindly did:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

as instructed by the person who wrote this code.

@Yavor's answer got me reading about autoloaders and [Autoloader optimization](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md) which is what that command does, it creates a file that maps class names to file names. While this is good for performance, the linked page specifically discourages optimization in dev environments: adding a new class renders the mapping file obsolete and incorrect, hence the errors.

After I removed the `vendor/composer` folder as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764532/1291717), things started working again.